# UICollectionViewCell with images

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

rI'm using a UICollectionView to display some images from the Web.
It works perfectly, but I have a problem with the size of the UIImageView containing my images...

I would like to fixe the width of each UIImageView, but the height will be adjust automatically to display a good resolution.

My question is: is it possible, after downloaded the image from the Web, get the height of my image and then, set the height programmatically in this method:

```
-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Thank you for your help.

Regards,
Lapinou.

Comment: Are you looking for image view's `contentMode` property?

Comment: I tried but the result is not really good, I think.